# Session id is different for each request

Tags: go, heroku, iris-go

On Heroku, I am using the `sessions` within the Iris framework for Go. Each time I make a request to the server from the browser page, the session ID is different.

My code:

When the application starts (global scope)

```
var appSession = sessions.New(sessions.Config{Cookie: "cookiesessionid"})
```

Incoming request

```
func post Request(ctx iris.Context) {

    sess := appSession.Start(ctx)
    sess := appSession.Start(ctx)
    fmt.Printf("%#v", sess)
}
```

Every time I run the request the session identifier revealed by the print statement, is different. Why would this be?

For what it's worth - the page is running out of an iframe.

Comment: Which browser are you using? I seem to recall that Safari ignores the Set-Cookie header for iframe responses, for instance. Use your browser's developer tool to verify that the cookie sticks.

Comment: I am using Chrome.

Comment: Every response that comes from my backend contains a new set-cookie header with new session id. Only on herokuapp.com and not localhost.

Comment: How can I fix??